# Accessing a frame name results on an "Access is denied" exception

Tags: c#, .net, browser, mshtml

I'm making a toolbar on C# for IE and I need to access a certain frame within the website. On my initial tests, I'm just trying to cycle through the frames and have a MessageBox popup with the name of the frame. But I'm encountering an exception whenever I try to do it, saying "Access is denied". The full text of the exception is:

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Here's the code:

```
IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = myHTMLDocument.selection;

IHTMLFramesCollection2 frames = (IHTMLFramesCollection2)myHTMLDocument.frames;

for (int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++)
{
    object refIndex = i;

    IHTMLWindow2 currentFrame = (IHTMLWindow2)frames.item(ref refIndex);

    if (currentFrame != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(currentFrame.name);
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Null");

}
```

From my searchs on the web, I found out that this is, in fact, not a bug. It's expected to behave that way. My question is: what is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've seen this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196340 , but I don't know if there is a more complete example in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting this message because you are trying to access a frame from another domain. The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) prevent you doing this. To make it work use IServiceProvider.

```
IServiceProvider isp = (IServiceProvider) currentFrame;
```

then query using `QueryService` to get IWebBrowser2 object.

Make sure you use `System.Runtime.InteropServices`